# Angular 2/4 | How can i get the API data with Token

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

Good day,

How can i get the api data with token using angular 2/4?

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class AppComponent {

private apiUrl = 'http://apiurlhere.xom/data';
data: any = {};

constructor(private http: Http){
    console.log('hi');
    this.getVoicepickData();
    this.getData();
}

//set API header
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Token': "XXXXXXXXXXTOKEN HEREXXXXXXXXXX",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    getData(){
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers: headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    }

    getVoicepickData() {
        this.getData().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data
        })
    }
}
```

i got error saying: Module parse failed: 'return' outside of function. can someone how me how to get the api data with token?? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a variable outside of the function scope. You can however set it as public property or within the function `getData` itself.

Hope this helps

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class AppComponent {

private apiUrl = 'http://apiurlhere.xom/data';
data: any = {};
headers: Headers;

constructor(private http: Http){
    console.log('hi');
    this.getVoicepickData();
    this.getData();

    this.headers = new Headers({
        'Token': "XXXXXXXXXXTOKEN HEREXXXXXXXXXX",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
}

    // YOU CANNOT SET SOMETHING HERE

    getData(){
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers: this.headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    getVoicepickData() {
        this.getData().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ow my bad, i didnt review my braces -,-

Comment: yeah, by the way im having error TS1005: ';' you know how to fix ths?

Comment: I've added a semicolon on a few places. That could be it. If not, you should debug your code yourself.